# There is a gap around my nav bar on all page except one

Tags: html, css, navbar

Code edited on 2017-01-09

Like i said, i have a gap around my nav bar on all my page except the main page. see the picture :

[This page is how it is suppose to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75SBl.png)

[This is how it appear (wrong) on all the other page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo8XV.png)

You can see a gap around the bar and also the heigh is not the same as the allignement. I tried to play with the heigh and padding but when i do the main page is also change and get to slim so we cant see all the text. i dont understand why it is not the same on all my page.

The things is that i use the same CSS code (same ID) for all the page that contain my nav bar.. Here is my code

For the main page (where the navbar is correct)

```css
/*background main page*/
#bodyprincipal_background {
 background-image: url("Grèce_background_1.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-color:#f1f1f1
}
/*background other pages*/
#image_background_general {
 background-image: url("grèce_background_texte_testeve1.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
}

/*nav bar uper right*/
#navbar_principal  {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
 background-color:#333 ;
 height: 60px;
}

#cat_navbar  {
 float: right;
}

#nom_navbar  {
 float: left;
}
#button_navbar {
  text-align: center;
     list-style-type: none;
  color: #99b3ff;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 8px ;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:#333 ;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*#99b3ff*/
} 

#button_navbar:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}

#button_nom  {
 color:#99b3ff;
 padding: 8px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: arial;
}
/* End of nav bar*/


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title> Bienvenu sur E-Démocratie !</title>
</head>

<body id="bodyprincipal_background">
<nav id="nav1">
<ul id="navbar_principal">
 <li id="nom_navbar"><p id="button_nom">E-Démocratie </p>
 <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="connexion.php">Connexion</a></li>
 <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="apropos.php">À propos</a></li>
 <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="contacte.php">Contacte</a></li>
 <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="accueil.php">Accueil</a></li>
</ul> 
</nav>
<h2 id="nom_accueil"> Bienvenu sur E-Démocratie ! </h1>
<h3 id="accueil_titre_2"> Revenons au fondement de la démocratie, par le peuple, pour le peuple.</h2>

<p id="description_accueil">
Notre site web vise à informez la population de façon neutre sur les enjeux de notre société.<br> 
Pourquoi ? : Le savoir c'est le pouvoir, informe toi et prends les choses en mains. </p>

<br>
<br>

<div id="etape1"> 
<p id="etape1">
"content"
</p>
</html>
```

And the last one is an exemple of a page where the navbar isnt correctly display:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body id="image_background_general">

<nav id="nav1">
 <ul id="navbar_principal">
  <li id="nom_navbar"><p id="button_nom">E-Démocratie </p>
  <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="connexion.php">Connexion</a></li>
  <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="apropos.php">À propos</a></li>
  <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="contacte.php">Contacte</a></li>
  <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="accueil.php">Accueil</a></li>
 </ul> 
</nav>

<h2 id="nom1"> Pour nous contacter </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copy the HTML below to begin working with a minimal Bootstrap document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

#### The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags

Next you should put these lines in your HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Next - you should move your `nav` from `head` into `body`.
Thus your second snippet has to look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title> Pour nous contacter </title>
</head>
<body id="image_background_general">
<nav id="nav1">
<ul id="navbar_principal">
    <li id="nom_navbar"><p id="button_nom">E-Démocratie </p>
    <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="connexion.php">Connexion</a></li>
    <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="apropos.php">À propos</a></li>
    <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="contacte.php">Contacte</a></li>
    <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="accueil.php">Accueil</a></li>
</ul> 
</nav>
<h1 id="nom1"> Pour nous contacter </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your anwser, i tried your step 1 and 3, they didn't work but when i tried your step 2 (wich i dont understand and thats why in first hand i have skipped this parts) and it finally work and display my nav bar like on my main page.  Would you mind to explain me in a few word what are those 3 line in your step 2 ? I would love to understand it !

Comment: (I also notice some change in the content of some page like the left margin are closer then before)

Comment: those lines, especially first one, required to link required styles to your page elements. such as nav bar, lists etc.

Answer (score 1):

your html output looks incorrect. You shouldn't have any of your page html inside the `<head>` tag. You need to put that all in the `<body>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title> Pour nous contacter </title>
</head>
<body id="image_background_general">
    <nav id="nav1">
        <ul id="navbar_principal">
            <li id="nom_navbar"><p id="button_nom">E-Démocratie </p>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="connexion.php">Connexion</a></li>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="apropos.php">À propos</a></li>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="contacte.php">Contacte</a></li>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="accueil.php">Accueil</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 id="nom1"> Pour nous contacter </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

You also are missing the closing body and html tags in your first code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title> Bienvenu sur E-Démocratie !</title>
</head>
<body id="bodyprincipal_background">
    <nav id="nav1">
        <ul id="navbar_principal">
            <li id="nom_navbar"><p id="button_nom">E-Démocratie </p>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="connexion.php">Connexion</a></li>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="apropos.php">À propos</a></li>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="contacte.php">Contacte</a></li>
            <li id="cat_navbar"><a id="button_navbar" href="accueil.php">Accueil</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </nav>
    <h1 id="nom_accueil"> Bienvenu sur E-Démocratie ! </h1>
    <h2 id="accueil_titre_2"> Revenons au fondement de la démocratie, par le peuple, pour le peuple.</h2>
    <p id="description_accueil">Page content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the missing tag, they where there its just that i didnt copy them on the snippet. I tried your solution and i move the nav out of the header but it didnt change the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The nav element is not supposed to go inside the head tag, it goes inside body (actually the head tag does not stand for "header").  Move the nav element and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I corrected my snippet and i tried again but i still have the same problem unfortunately.